# Firebase Analytics - How to see specific content and not a controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, firebase-analytics

I have an app full of stories, and I want to see which stories users are reading.

I already installed Firebase Analytics, but all I'm seeing is this kind of content:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to be able to see the specific title of the stories users are reading.

This is the ForEach loop I'm using:

```
 ForEach(modelData.stories.shuffled()) { item in
                    if item.paid == false {
                        NavigationLink {
                            StoryDetails(story: item)
                        } label: {
                            GeneralCard(isLocked: false, story: item)
                        }

                    }
                }
```

And on StoryDetails I have this code, I would like to see the title of the story inside Firebase Analytics.

```
VStack (spacing: 0) {
                Text(story.title)
                    .font(AppFont.detailTitle())
                    .bold()
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .foregroundColor(.mainColor)
                
                Text(story.category.rawValue)
                    .font(AppFont.detailDescription())
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.mainColor)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                    
                    ForEach(story.text, id: \.self) { item in
                        VStack {
                            Text(item)
                                .font(AppFont.detailText())
                        }
                    }
                }
                //.padding(.horizontal, 10)
            }
```

Is this something that can be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could set this up by manually logging your screenviews instead. For SwiftUI, it is something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, world!")
       // Logging screen name with class and a custom parameter.
      .analyticsScreen(name: "main_content",
                       class: "ContentView",
                       extraParameters: ["my_custom_param": 5])

      // OR Logging screen name only, class and extra parameters are optional.
      .analyticsScreen(name: "main_content")
  }
}
```